# Is a Canadian IEC work permit limited by passport expiration date, and if so can it be extended later?

Tags: visa, working-visas, canada, passport, ireland

I am from Ireland. My application for a Canadian working holiday visa has been accepted (through the IEC programme, I have my Port of Entry letter, and when I arrive I should get a work permit). It is a 2 year visa, and I want to stay for the full 2 years.

I plan to go to Canada in March 2015, but my Irish passport expires in May 2016.

If I arrive in Canada with this passport, will I only be able to get a work permit up until May 2016? This would limit my 2 year visa to 14 months.

If it is limited by my passport expiring, can I extend this afterwards so that I can stay for the full 2 years? (assuming I can renew my passport while I am in Canada)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, you will not be able to receive a work permit for the full 2 years, because according to [Citizenship and Immigration Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/iec/index.asp?country=ie&cat=wh),

> your work permit in Canada will not be longer than the validity of your passport

And unfortunately, it appears that you can't extend this afterwards. [The CIC says that](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?q=846&t=25)

> International Experience Canada (IEC) participants cannot renew or extend their work permits under IEC.

[Another CIC help page](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?q=942&t=25) suggests that to spend more time working in Canada, you could either apply through another (non-IEC) program, or a "second participation" in IEC. However, this second participation might not be useful for you, as seen on [the first link](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/iec/index.asp?country=ie&cat=wh):

> As an Irish citizen, you may participate in the Working Holiday category only once. If you meet the eligibility criteria, you may participate in IEC one more time through the International Co-op (Internship) category.